# Is there an equivalent to ASP.NET "IsPostBack" in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I use frame to load pages in my WPF project, is there a way to detect a page loading is the first or not? Something like "IsPostBack" in ASP.NET, I'm trying to find an equivalent to it in WPF.

I found IsPostBack is a property in System.Web.UI, should I include this namespace in my page?

I still have to use a static variable "bool SystemLoad = true", at the first load it is True and then I set it to False, so when the page is reloaded, it doesn't do as at the first load.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

IsPostBack is not relevant to a WPF application, and since your WPF application window does not inherit 'Page', there is no way you can use IsPostBack variable from System.Web.UI.

The best you can do is to implement your custom logic as below.

```
private bool isLoaded;
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isLoaded)
        return;
    isLoaded = true;
}
```